# MySQL select from 2 tables without having "shared" key

Tags: mysql, select

Searched the site and found some similar questions, but none of solutions worked in my case.

I have 2 tables - clients and memberships.

The structure is following:

```
clients
client_id
other_fields...

memberships
membership_id
client_id
other_fields...
```

The field submitted to form is "membership_id". Let's say submitted value is 5. I want to use a single query to select all fields from memberships and clients where

`clients.client_id=memberships.client_id AND memberships.membership_id!=5`

(select other memberships except submitted one). But I need to select only records of client who has membership_id 5 (records of other clients and memberships should not be selected)

Used `SELECT memberships.*, clients.* FROM memberships AS memberships, clients AS clients WHERE memberships.client_id=clients.client_id AND memberships.membership_id!=5` but this query displays memberships of all clients. And I need to have memberships only of client who also has membership_id 5.

The problem is that I don't know original client_id, so I can't include it in query

Comment: It would help if you show some sample input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to the end:

```
and exists(select * from memberships m 
           where m.membership_id = 5 and m.client_id = clients.client_id )
```